# Config for external (eg. bower) plugins

Tags: gruntjs

How can I use an configuration file (config.json) for easier grunt setup

I want to add/setup all needed plugins in my config.json and I want a seperated file for all Plugins or seperate FOlder for images

**config.json**

```
{
    "images": {
        "pluginA": [
            "./faces/*.jpg"
        ],
        "pluginB": [
            "./corpes/*.jpg"
        ]
    },
    "javascript": {
        "pluginA": [
            "./faces/*.js"
        ],
        "pluginB": [
            "./corpes/*.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
plugins: grunt.file.readJSON('plugins_config.json')
jshint: {
    development: {
        files: {
            **plugins.javascript**
        }
    }
}
```

**desired output**

dist/

- images

  - pluginA

    - faces1.jpg
    - faces2.jpg
  - pluginB

    - corpes1.jpg
    - corpes2.jpg
- javascript

  - pluginA.js
  - pluginB.js
- styles

  - pluginA.css
  - pluginB.css

Answer (score 0):

The way you usually access a grunt config is through the method `grunt.config(key)`, so your json file is accessible through `grunt.config('plugins')`.
Unfortunately the config object is initialized by `grunt.initConfig`, so you can't use it in the call to initConfig itself, which is what you need to do.

Your solution is to use a separate local variable **outside** initConfig, instead of a config:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var plugins = grunt.file.readJSON('plugins_config.json');
  // ...
  grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        development: {
            files: {
              src: plugins.javascript.pluginA,
            }
        }
    },
  // ...
  });
};
```